# Pgf/Tikz: Create figure using CAD-Software?

Tags: tikz-pgf, 3d

I have created a 3D model using open source CAD-Software called FreeCad (computer-aided design). I can export step files from it. I would like to include the CAD-Drawing into a LaTeX file, but the standard output is not consistent with the rest of my document. Is there a way to create tikz figures from CAD software files? I would be glad if someone could provide some resources or references for tasks like this.

[Here](https://github.com/FreeCAD/FreeCAD-library/tree/master/Architectural%20Parts/Doors/Generic) is a link to the FreeCAD Library if someone needs a step file to see if it works.

Comment: If you can export to SVG that could be a good start. Presumably, you want to have a Tikz version of the 2D rendered model. If FreeCAD can export the render to SVG then there is hope (for example you can export a SVG to Tikz using Inkscape)

Comment: Thank you for this comment. I will try this out as soon as I have time. Maybe that would solve my problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FreeCAD has the option to [export to SVG](https://yorikvanhavre.gitbooks.io/a-freecad-manual/content/working_with_freecad/generating_2d_drawings.html).

Once you have an SVG version of your drawing, you can proceed by either:

1. producing a PDF of it and use `\includegraphics` to import it in your LaTeX document, optionally using TikZ to annotate it or further enrich the contents.
2. Using [`svg2tikz`](https://github.com/kjellmf/svg2tikz) to convert the SVG to TikZ code

For manipulation of the SVG itself, I recommend the free [Inkscape](https://inkscape.org) program.