# Is there a way to prepare a TikZ diagram for use with a laser cutter?

Tags: tikz-pgf, export

I am hoping to print a fancy TikZ diagram I made in a vector format so that a laser cutter can cut it out of a piece of paper once printed.

Is there a way to output a TikZ diagram in such a format? I'm specifically thinking of AI or DXF. (I understand some laser cutters use EPS, SVG or PDF...but alas! The one I have access to does not support those formats!)

Better yet, is there a way I can output only part of that image for the laser cutter?

Comment: @close voters: I think this question is on topic, i.e., the question is "how to convert TikZ diagrams to AI or DXF", in line with many other convert from/to TikZ questions that we have. I also think that the answer is "that is not possible" but maybe I'm wrong and someone can answer this with a practical approach.

Comment: @Marijn: Thanks for the accurate clarification. (Many people vote close too quickly!) It's possible *in theory* either by translating LaTeX/TikZ source code to one of those formats *or* by translating the output PDF to one of those formats. I don't expect anyone to write the translation software for this, though!! I know (software exists)[https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/391984/25653] to convert SVG diagrams to TikZ...so it should be doable in reverse, too.